# How to connect containerized flask server to containerized postgres db docker?

Tags: docker

I have two containers - one is a postgres container, the other a python server. I'm trying to connect the two, to no avail.

The command for postgres container is the following. The `postgres` image is the official one:

```
docker run -dp 1000:5432 --name postgres_db_mapped -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword 
-v postgre_sql_config:/etc/postgresql 
-v postgre_sql_logs:/var/log/postgresql 
-v postgre_sql_data:/var/lib/postgresql 
postgres
```

I can use the `psql` command at port 1000 locally to access the db, and commands run fine so I know its working.

The python server consists of a dockerfile, and obviously some python scripts. I won't paste the whole docker file because I think most is straightforward. I'll share the final `CMD` however:

```
CMD [ "gunicorn", "src.wsgi:app","--bind","0.0.0.0:5001" ]
```

This is the `settings.py` associated with the server, and I think *maybe* the root of the issues. Out the box, this is the file:

```
FINCREX_CS="postgres:mysecretpassword@127.0.0.1:1000/my-db"
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI =  'postgresql://' + FINCREX_CS
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

There are a set of flask files that I believe are fine, and atleast try to connect to the postgres db.

I build the python image as `my-api` then run it as so:

```
docker container run  -p 5001:5001 my-api
```

The server looks like it boots successfully. But when I try to hit an endpoint that attempts to hit the db, I get the following error

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 1000?
```

I've been changing the `FINCREX_CS` in a few ways to try to get it to connect. I've tried to following:

```
"postgres:mysecretpassword@postgres_db_mapped:1000/my-db" //use container name instead of localhost (localhost would be referring to the localhost of the python container)
"postgres:mysecretpassword@postgres_db_mapped:5432/my-db" // 5432 is docker port of the postgres container"
```

But neither have seemed to work. I know they are both in the bridge network. `docker inspect bridge` prints the following:

```
       "Containers": {
            "4e138792bd2d257ad169d0100f1be39c176dd0a955e2792ad6284b3966c93dcd": {
                "Name": "eloquent_bouman", //the python server
                "EndpointID": "f87bdf444fda6d67a78e44b3f6cd186c1d4265f161d58d918edd4a22c91da7a5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "63e1a299f44d092558786d8c01e9a8d322f5731c6d6b16425568138bf12ba9b1": {
                "Name": "postgres_db_mapped",
                "EndpointID": "de519b83a7dcf026139edf183092f0c4c89f73d7679477c8035bd4f08c8f0ff4",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

Comment: You need to `docker network create` a network, and then `docker run --net` both containers on the same network.  They can use each other's `docker run --name` container names as host names.  127.0.0.1 or `localhost` in Docker typically means "this container", not another container or the host system.

Comment: I didn't specify a network - doesn't that mean they're both in the `bridge` network? How would I refer to the postgres container in the url string? I believe I had tried that as `"postgres:mysecretpassword@postgres_db_mapped:5432/my-db"`

Comment: If you don't specify `--net` they're in the [default bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#use-the-default-bridge-network) which isn't very useful; it doesn't support things like connecting to other containers by name without additional options, and it's generally considered obsolete.